# the c++ programming language, chapter 5.9 exercise 1

Tags: c++

From the book:

> Write declarations for the following: a pointer to a character, an
>   array of 10 integers, a ref-erence to an array of 10 integers, a
>   pointer to an array of character strings, a pointer to a pointer to a
>   character, a constant integer, a pointer to a constant integer, and a
>   constant pointer to an integer. Initialize each one.

I'm confused by "a pointer to an array of character strings". What does Stroustrup want? Is this to be meant literally? In which way?

The straight and simple solution:

```
char* c[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
char** c_ptr;
```

Or this one:

```
typedef char carray[20];
typedef array* carray_ptr;
carray_ptr ptr = new carray[10];
```

What do you think? (Okay, a pointer to pointer isn't very straight.)

Comment: `Initiating Stroustrup mind-reading system. Standby for takeoff...`

Comment: The book seems to be good. Better than the german "C++ von A bis Z", translated "C++ from A to Z". But exercises without solutions are - not helpful. Even if the "companion book" would be available, I wouldn't buy it.

Answer (score 2):

With these sorts of declaration tests, it's often easiest to use a tool like `cdecl`.  I think in this case what the book is looking for is:

```
c
```

is a pointer:

```
*c
```

to an array:

```
(*c)[]
```

of character strings:

```
char *(*c)[]
```

Or from `cdecl`:

```
cdecl> declare c as pointer to array of pointer to char
char *(*c)[]
```

I just made a guess about what the book expects, but since the next request is "pointer to a pointer to a character", it would be weird for the two to be asking the same thing.

Comment: Looks neat to me! Thank you! Stroustrup doesn't show this in his samples during the chapter, only a line about pointer to functions. I'm looking forward to the next chapter (includes operator precedence), which should help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef char* character_string;
typedef character_string[20] array_of_character_strings;
typedef array_of_character_strings* pointer_to_array_of_character_strings;
pointer_to_array_of_character_strings ptr; //done
```

or:

```
char*(*var)[20];
```

shown at: [cdecl.ridiculousfish.com](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char%2a%28%2avar%29%5B20%5D), "declare var as pointer to array 20 of pointer to char"

Answer (score 0):

1) Chapter 5 is about "Pointers, Arrays and Structures".
   I don't see any "typedef's" skimming the chapter, so I wouldn't use them in this exercise.

2) One could point to "argv" as an excellent example of "A pointer to an array of character strings":

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

3) "c_ptr" in your first example would certainly work (although maybe a better name
   might be "c_pp" ;)):

```
char* c[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
char** c_ptr = c;
```

'Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into steps:

1. A pointer to an array: `T (*p)[N]`
2. `T = char const *` gives you: `char const * (*p)[N]`
3. We initialize a pointer with the address of an existing thing, so make an array first:

   `char const * arr[] = { "hello", "world" };`
4. Now initialize the guy from (2): `char const * (*p)[2] = &arr;`